# UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not work on Custom MKMapViewAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have a custom pin.UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not work on that pin as I implemented as below, any ideas?

```
    - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
           NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
          }
         else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
          }
    }


    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[NewBBAnnotation class]]){
        NewBBAnnotation *cu=(NewBBAnnotation*)annotation;
        DealerPinView *cur= (DealerPinView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:cu.custCode];
        if(cur==nil)
            cur=[[DealerPinView alloc] initWithAnnotationAndButton:annotation reuseIdentifier:cu.custCode];
        else
            cur.annotation=annotation;
        [cur drawPinAnnotation:@"market" pinName:@"market" hasRedFlag:NO hasTimerFlag:NO longTouchPressed:NO isTransparent:NO isRemoteVisit:NO];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        [cur setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
        longPress.delegate = self;
        [cur addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
            return cur;
    }
    else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    return nil;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Long press gesture does not work.